# I am having a problem with a fluxing home made electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism

I made a home made electromagnet, and unlike my store bought electromagnet, the home made one is jumping and fluxing on and off. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Of course there's a reason for this. But we can't possibly tell with exactly no information given.

Comment: There is a 5 mm soft iron core, with 10 wraps of coil 4 times making it 40. There is a there is a 12 dcv power source